# Converting List<string> to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

While I know that converting lists to dictionaries has been discussed a lot of times, I can't find the solution to a specific problem I have.

I'm working with DocX/Xceed to edit Word documents (.docx). I decided to use the example in the documentation to replace words in a document, said example uses a `Dictionary<string, string>` where the key is the word to be replaced and the value the word to replace it with. In my case I want to use the inputs from over 40 text boxes in my form to replace words so I made a temporary list where I store both the words I want to replace and the input of the textboxes, for this I use the following method:

```
List<string> dictlist = new List<string>();
foreach (Control tb in grpBoxTxt.Controls)
{
    if (tb is TextBox)
    {
        dictlist.Add("Test" + a.ToString());
        dictlist.Add(tb.Text.ToString());
        a++;
    }
}
```

This gives me a list with both the words to replace (in this example Test followed by a number) and the input from the textboxes, from here I convert the list to a dictionary I previously defined:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> _replacePatterns = new Dictionary<string, string>();
_replacePatterns = dictlist.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x, y => y);
```

This is the part where I get a problem, instead of getting the Test words as the keys and input as values, the words repeat themselves so I end up with a dictionary that has for example *Test1* and *Test1* as the key and value.

What exactly am I doing wrong? From what I understand the expression I use while converting the list to dictionary is correct but I'm not getting the results I need.

Comment: You're adding consecutive values for the before / after pairs? That's just creating a world of hurt. First, i'd create a `List<(TextBox before, TextBox after)>` (or `Dictionary<...,TextBox>`). Then you can `.ToDictionary(p => p.before.Text, p.after.Text)`.

Comment: why even create a list in the firstplace, and not start with a dictionary? if you still need it as a list somewhere, you can still convert the dictionary - with much less effort: `lst = dct.SelectMany(e => new []{e.Key, e.Value}).ToList()`

Comment: My logic for the list was that I couldn't use an iterating loop to add the values to the dictionary and I would need to manually type the textbox.text with the appropiate tag to be replaced.

Comment: @MrsClefairy - yes you can. `dct["Test"+a.ToString()] = tb.Text.ToString();`

Comment: Thank you t hat worked, I was using a different syntax which gave me an error which is why I thought I could not use an iterating loop, I see now that I was wrong and it was possible, thank you again!